# Visual Studio and MySQL, doesn't modify any data

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

It seems like i do connect to my database judging by no error messege after executing the code but i'm unable to do INSERT INTO command even though it works if i copy the code to sql server command line client. What did i do wrong ?
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q24Nb.png)

Comment: Kirby, please add the code to SO by _editing_ your question. INSERT INTO tblName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('val1', 'val2', 'val3')

Comment: Please copy the code as text and paste it inside your question using the edit button

Comment: Sorry but it just wasn't looking too good with just half of text being pasted in a good looking way and rest just molding together...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some code is off the bottom of the screen there but, you will need to execute the command.  Something like:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, before doing that you should indicate that it's a text command

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i've actually solved it, thanks comment above for helping me at least slightly. After i posted your code it didn't work but when i moved it under the open like that :

> ```
>     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
>         con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
>         MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
>         try
>         {
>             con.Open();
>         }
>         catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
>         }
>         cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DaneRecepcjonistki VALUES('123', 'Kot', 'Pies');";
>         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
>         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>     } It works !
> ```
>
> Thanks !